# Is it true that a subset that is closed in a closed subspace of a topological space is closed in the whole space?

Tags: general-topology

I have a non homework related question from a text and require a nice clear proof/disproof
please

Is it true that a subset that is closed in a closed subspace of a topological
space is closed in the whole space?

my ideas:

if $H$ is the subset of the topological space $X$

if the subset is closed in the closed subspace, the complement is open in the subspace, which means the complement is of form $U\cap H$ for some $U$ open in $X$

if the subspace is closed the complement is open which means complement of $H=U$ for some open $U$ in $X$

kind thanks

Comment: This is useful i connection with your question: 
[Closed Set in Topological Subspace](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Closed_Set_in_Topological_Subspace)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Suppose that $H$ is a closed subspace of $X$, and $F$ is closed in the subspace $H$. By definition of the relative topology there is a closed set $C$ in $X$ such that $F=C\cap H$. But then $F$ is the intersection of two closed subsets of $X$, so $F$ is closed in $X$.

If you don’t already know this characterization of closed sets in the relative topology, it’s worth proving as a separate

> **Proposition.** Let $Y$ be a subspace of a space $X$. Then a set $H\subseteq Y$ is closed in $Y$ if and only if $H=F\cap Y$ for some closed set $F$ in $X$.

Of course for this you do need to look at complements, but it’s very easy. $Y\setminus H$ is open in $Y$, so there is an open $U\subseteq X$ such that $Y\setminus H=U\cap Y$. Let $F=X\setminus U$; then $F$ is closed in $X$, and $F\cap Y=(X\setminus U)\cap Y=Y\setminus U=H$.

Comment: The definition of the subspace topology with which I am familiar says that open sets in the subspace topology have the form $G\cap H$ where $H$ is the subspace and $G$ is open in $X$.  Then the statement you made in your third sentence is a theorem, and although it's simple, it seems to require exactly the sort of consideration of complements that you claim can be avoided.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @MJD: No. I’ve internalized the concept to such an extent that I simply didn’t think of that as a separate result. I should probably rephrase. (Of course, if one defines a topology in terms of closed sets, one will presumably define the relative topology similarly, but that’s hardly likely to be relevant here!)

Comment: Why $Y=(X\setminus U)\cap Y=Y\setminus U=H$ ?

Comment: Is it true that a closed subset in an open subspace is also closed in the whole space?

Comment: @FreeZe: Not necessarily: $(0,1]$ is closed in $(0,2)$ but not in $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X'$ be a closed subset of $X$, and say that $H$ is closed in $X'$ in the subspace topology.  Then $X'\setminus H$ is open in $X'$, and is therefore of the form $G\cap X'$ for some set $G$ that is open in $X$.  Then $X\setminus G$ is closed in $X$, and $(X\setminus G)\cap X' = H$ is an intersection of sets closed in $X$ and is thus closed in $X$.