# $X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ is a "basic" cover if for all $U\in X$, $U$ is open in $X$ iff $\forall i,U\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$

Tags: general-topology

$X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ is a "basic" cover if for all $U\in X$, $U$ is open in $X$ iff $\forall i,U\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$. This is a definition and the only reason it is the one to appear in the subject is that the definition seems to not exist, partially because the term "basic" rings no bell. 
**The question** asked then is:

> Prove that $X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ is a *basic cover* iff for all $U\subset X$, if $U\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ for all $i$ then $U$ is open.

I cant seem to have any approach. I am not even sure I have percepted the definition right. Doesn't $U\in X$ simply mean $U=A_i$ for some $i$? Does $U\in X$ mean a union? I am perplexed and would appreciate it if you could assist me.

Comment: The definition given in the first sentence of the question makes no sense. If $U\in X$, then $U$ is an *element* of $X$, and openness is a property of sets, not of points.

Comment: The question, to be accurate, stated "U in X", which still makes no sense in my opinion, unless it refers a component in the union. It was translated but it makes no bigger sense in the original wording.

Comment: In English ‘for all $U$ in $X$’ could be a sloppy version of ‘for all $U\subseteq X$’. If that’s the case here, the definition and the version in the question actually are slightly different. The definition says that the sets $A_i$ form a basic cover if $U\subseteq X$ is open in $X$ if **and only if** each $U\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$. The question then asks you to prove that we could drop **and only if** from the definition without changing the meaning of *basic cover*.

Comment: I was thinking in the same manner but I am unfortunately challenged reading your last sentence. Was it a way to say my job there is really to show one side of the statement?

Comment: The definition says that the following are equivalent: (a) the $A_i$ are a basic open cover, and (b) $U\subseteq X$ is open if **and only if** each $U\cap A_i$ is relatively open in $A_i$. The question asks you to show that (a) is equivalent to (c) $U\subseteq X$ is open if each $U\cap A_i$ is relatively open in $A_i$. In other words, it’s asking you to show that (c) implies (b): if $U\subseteq X$ is open whenever all $U\cap A_i$ are relatively open, then every open subset of $X$ has relatively open intersection with each $A_i$.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I am very thankful for this thorough integration.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, is one direction already proved?

Comment: Yes, (b) clearly implies (c).

Comment: My work here begins with assuming that there exists a cover $\bigcup_{i}A_i$ such that for all $U\subset X$ satisfying $U\cap A_i$ for all $i$, $U$ is open, doesn't it? 
All those "iff"'s really made it look like a maze to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me give you some details about the definition:

> **Definition**. We say that $X=\bigcup\limits_{i \in I}A_i$ is a *basic cover* of $X$ if for all $U \subset X$, 
>   $$U \text{ is open in } X
> \;\;\iff\;\;
> \forall i \in I,\; U\cap A_i \text{ is open in } A_i.$$

You have to write $U \subset X$ and not $U \in X$. Here $U$ is a *subset* of $X$, not an element.

Here is a (non-)example. For instance, $\Bbb R = \bigcup_{i \in \Bbb R} \{i\}$ is not a basic cover since $U=\{5\}$ is not open in $\Bbb R$, but
$U \cap \{i\}$ is always open in $\{i\}$.

$$ $$

---

Let's turn to the given problem.

> Prove that $X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ is a *basic cover* iff for all $U\subset X$, if $U\cap A_i$ is open in $A_i$ for all $i$ then $U$ is open.

Therefore, we have to prove that  $X=\bigcup_{i}A_i$ is a *basic cover* if and only if we have the following property (let me call it the property **(Q)**):

> For every subset $U \subset X$,
>   $$\forall i \in I,\; U\cap A_i \text{ is open in } A_i
> \;\;\implies\;\;
> U \text{ is open in } X$$

Hence, we have to show that the following property **(P)** (which is exactly the definiton of "basic cover" given above):

> For all $U \subset X$, 
>   $$
> \forall i \in I,\; U\cap A_i \text{ is open in } A_i
> \;\;\iff\;\;
> U \text{ is open in } X.$$

is equivalent to the above property **(Q)**.

You can see that **(P)** and **(Q)** are very similar:

- **(P)** has the form $\phi \iff \psi$
- **(Q)** has the form $\phi \implies \psi$

(where $\phi$ denotes "$\forall i \in I,\; U\cap A_i \text{ is open in } A_i$" and $\psi$ denotes "$U \text{ is open in } X$").

$$ $$
$$ $$
What does it mean to be "open in $A_i$" ?
Let $B \subset X$ be any subset of $X$.

> **Definition**
>   A subset $V \subset B$ is said to be open in $B$ iff
>   there is an open set $W \subset X$ such that
>   $V = W \cap B$.

By the above definition of the subspace topology, we have
$$U \text{ is open in } X \implies \forall B \subset X,\; U\cap B \text{ is open in } B$$
because you just have to take $W=U$ (and here $V=U \cap B$).

Applying this to any $B = A_i$, we get
$$U \text{ is open in } X \implies \forall i \in I,\; U\cap A_i \text{ is open in } A_i$$

which is $\psi \implies \phi$.
$$ $$

From all this, I think you should be able to prove that

- **(P)** implies **(Q)** (easy)
- **(Q)** implies **(P)** : assume that **(Q)** is true, i.e. $\phi \implies \psi$ is true. You want to show that **(P)** is true, i.e. $\phi \iff \psi$ is true.  By what I've said above, $\psi \implies \phi$ is always true. By assumption, you know that $\phi \implies \psi$ is also true. Therefore, you can easily conclude that $$\phi \iff \psi$$ (which is **(P)**) is also true, as desired.

Therefore **(Q)** and **(P)** are equivalent, as desired.

$$ $$

---

From very similar arguments, you can replace the open sets $U$ by closed sets $F$ in the definiton, [since](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/314000) 
$F$ closed in $X \implies F \cap B$ closed in $B$ for any $B \subset X$.