# Counterexample: relatively closed subset in A but not in the whole metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I understand that if A is open in the metric space (M,d), then for any $G \subset A$ we have that G is open in A iff G is open in M. But if we replace the word "open" with "closed", I don't believe it's true. I'm trying to find a counterexample using a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, to no avail.

Comment: This seems to have been answered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/313991/is-it-true-that-a-subset-that-is-closed-in-a-closed-subspace-of-a-topological-sp

Comment: well let $G = A$.  $A$ is both open and closed in $A$ but it is only open in $M$.

Comment: Or for that matter if $A = (0,2)\subset \mathbb R$ and $G = [1,2)$ is closed in $A$.  If $G$ is a set that contains all it's limit points that are in $A$ but none of its limit points that aren't in $A$...

Comment: The comments above, and the answer, assume that you still want $A$ to be open, and are just asking about the closedness of $G$.  The link I posted is for the case where $A$ is also taken to be closed.  Which instances of "open" were supposed to be replaced by "closed"?

Comment: Sorry I meant to replace all instances of "open". So A is presumed closed too.

Comment: @ChrisEagle That link proves the forward implication. But I think the backwards implication is also true. Let $A$ as well as $G \subset A$ be closed in M. Since $G = G \cap A$, G is closed in A.

Comment: If $G\subset A$ then every limit point of $G$ is a limit point of $A$.  If $A$ is closed then every limit point of $G$ is a point in $A$. So $G$ is closed in $A$ if and only if every limit point of $G$ that is in $A$ is in $G$ if and only if every limit point of $G$ that is in $M$ is in $G$ if and only if $G$ is closed in $M$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $G$ being closed in $A$ means that $G$ contains all its limit points (that are in $A$), whereas the definition of $G$ being closed in $M$  means that $G$ contains all it limit points (in $M$).

So to find a counter-example we need a set $G$ that has limit points that are not in $A$ but of all the limit points that are in $A$ are in $G$.

So let's take a case where $G$ is not closed.  Let's say $G= (0,1)$.  It has limit points $0, 1$ and all the points $(0,1)$.  $0$ and $1$ are not in $G$ so if $0,1$ are not in $A$ we will be fine.  The points $x: 0 < x < 1$ are all in $G$ so $(0,1)\subset A$ but $0,1 \not \in A$ will be good.

SO if $A = (0,1)$ then $G=(0,1) \subset A$ is closed in $A$.

For a less trivial example so $A = (0,1) \cup (2,3)$.  $G=(0,1)$ is closed in $A$.

For a more subtle case.  If $G = [0,1)$ then $G$ has all its limit points except $1$  in $G$.  If $1\not \in A$ and $G\subset A$ and $A $ is open this will work.  Let $A = \mathbb R\setminus \{1\}$.  Then $G$ is closed in $A$ but not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to replace all instances of "open". So A is presumed closed too.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is closed in $M$ then $B \subseteq A$ is closed in $A$ iff $B$ is closed in $M$. This is immediate from the definition of the subspace topology, and holds in all spaces, not just metric ones.